# Read a text file with regexp and store into structure

Tags: regex, matlab, struct, io

I everybody,

I'm trying to parse a text file into matlab: it consists of several blocks (START_BLOCK/END_BLOCK) where are allocated strings (variable) and values (associated to the previous variables).

An example is this:

```
START_BLOCK_EXTREMEWIND
velocity_v1 29.7


velocity_v50    44.8


velocity_vred1  32.67
velocity_vred50 49.28


velocity_ve1    37.9



velocity_ve50   57


velocity_vref   50



END_BLOCK_EXTREMEWIND
```

Currently, my code is:

```
fid = fopen('test_struct.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid,'%s %f32 %*[^\n]','CollectOutput',true);
C{1} = reshape(C{1},1,numel(C{1}));
C{2} = reshape(C{2},1,numel(C{2}));



startIdx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C{1}, 'START_BLOCK_', 'match')));
endIdx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C{1}, 'END_BLOCK_', 'match')));
assert(all(size(startIdx) == size(endIdx)))
extract_parameters = @(n)({C{1}{startIdx(n)+1:endIdx(n) - 1}});
parameters = arrayfun(extract_parameters, 1:numel(startIdx), 'UniformOutput', false);

s = cell2struct(cell(size(parameters{1})),parameters{1}(1:numel(parameters{1})),2);

s.velocity_v1 = C{2}(2);
s.velocity_v50 = C{2}(3);
s.velocity_vred1 = C{2}(4);
s.velocity_vred50 = C{2}(5);
s.velocity_ve1 = C{2}(6);
s.velocity_ve50 = C{2}(7);
s.velocity_vref = C{2}(8);
```

It works, but it's absolutely static. I would rather have a code able to:

```
1. check the existence of blocks --> as already implemented;
2. the strings are to be taken as fields of the structure;
3. the numbers are meant to be the attributes of each field.
```

Finally, if there is more than one block, there should be and iteration about those blocks to get the whole structure.
It's the first time I approach structure coding at all, so please be patient.

I thank you all in advance.

Kindest regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you will want to make use of dynamic field names.  If you have a struct `s`, a string `fieldName` that stores the name of a field, and `fieldVal` which holds the value that you'd like to set for this field, then you can use the following syntax to perform the assignment:

```
s.(fieldName) = fieldVal;
```

This MATLAB [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1v5cc-1.html) provides further info.

With this in mind, I took a slightly different approach to parse the text.  I iterated through the text with a for loop.  Although for loops are sometimes frowned upon in MATLAB (since MATLAB is optimized for vectorized operations), I think in this case it helps to make the code cleaner.  Furthermore, my understanding is that if you are having to make use of `arrayfun`, then replacing this with a for loop probably won't really cause much of a performance hit, anyway.

The following code will convert each block in the text to a struct with the specified fields and values.  These resulting "block" structs are then added to a higher-level "result" struct.

```
fid = fopen('test_struct.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid,'%s %f32 %*[^\n]','CollectOutput',true);
fclose(fid);

paramNames = C{1};
paramVals = C{2};

curBlockName = [];
inBlock = 0;
blockCount = 0;

%// Iterate through all of the entries in "paramNames".  Each block will be a
%// new struct that is then added to a high-level "result" struct.
for i=1:length(paramNames)
    curParamName = paramNames{i};
    isStart = ~isempty(regexp(curParamName, 'START_BLOCK_', 'match'));
    isEnd = ~isempty(regexp(curParamName, 'END_BLOCK_', 'match'));

    %// If at the start of a new block, create a new struct with a single
    %// field - the BlockName (as specified by the text after "START_BLOCK_"
    if(isStart)
        assert(inBlock == 0);
        curBlockName = curParamName(length('START_BLOCK_') + 1:end);
        inBlock = 1;
        blockCount = blockCount + 1;
        s = struct('BlockName', curBlockName);          

    %// If at the end of a block, add the struct that we've just populated to
    %// our high-level "result" struct.
    elseif(isEnd)
        assert(inBlock == 1);
        inBlock = 0;
        %// EDIT - storing result in "structure of structures"
        %//  rather than array of structs
        %// s_array(blockCount) = s;
        result.(curBlockName) = s;

    %// Otherwise, assume that we are inside of a block, so add the current
    %// parameter to the struct.
    else
        assert(inBlock == 1);
        s.(curParamName) = paramVals(i);
    end
end

%// Results stored in "result" structure
```

Hopefully this answers your question... or at least provides some helpful hints.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but your code has still the staticity due to the same number of fields for each block: my text file usually consists of several block characterized by several fields. I was thinking to read each block separately in a structure called with the part of text after START_BLOCK_ and the merge them all together in a "structure of structures". I will try to work on it. I thank you again for your hints :)

Comment: @FrancescoPerrone - I see. If I understand correctly, this will still make use of the concept of dynamic fields, and really just requires a one line change to the code.  Simply replace the line `s_array(blockCount) = s` with `result.(curBlockName) = s`.  I've edited my code, above, accordingly.  Now this code creates a "structure of structures" named `result`.  Each block can have completely different fields, now.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code today and now it almost works as meant to be:

```
clc, clear all, close all

%Find all row headers
fid = fopen('test_struct.txt','r');
row_headers = textscan(fid,'%s %*[^\n]','CommentStyle','%','CollectOutput',1);
row_headers = row_headers{1};
fclose(fid);

%Find all attributes
fid1 = fopen('test_struct.txt','r');
attributes = textscan(fid1,'%*s %s','CommentStyle','%','CollectOutput',1);
attributes = attributes{1};
fclose(fid1);

%Collect row headers and attributes in a single cell
parameters = [row_headers,attributes];


%Find all the blocks
startIdx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(parameters, 'BLOCK_START_', 'match')));
endIdx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(parameters, 'BLOCK_END_', 'match')));
assert(all(size(startIdx) == size(endIdx)))


%Extract fields between BLOCK_START_ and BLOCK_END_
extract_fields = @(n)(parameters(startIdx(n)+1:endIdx(n)-1,1));
struct_fields = arrayfun(extract_fields, 1:numel(startIdx), 'UniformOutput', false);

%Extract attributes between BLOCK_START_ and BLOCK_END_
extract_attributes = @(n)(parameters(startIdx(n)+1:endIdx(n)-1,2));
struct_attributes = arrayfun(extract_attributes, 1:numel(startIdx), 'UniformOutput', false);


for i = 1:numel(struct_attributes)
    s{i} = cell2struct(struct_attributes{i},struct_fields{i},1);
end
```

Now, in the end, I get a cell of stuctures that could, let's say, fulfill my requirements. The only point that I would like to improve is:

```
- Give each structure the name of the respective block.
```

Does anybody have valuable hints?

Thank you all for supporting me.

Regards,
Francesco

Comment: With regards to your request to "Give each structure the name of the respective block" I think that my edited answer above should help you with this.  In the code that I provided all results are saved in a struct `result` that contains multiple "sub-structures" for each block.  Again, I used the dynamic field name syntax to name each of these sub-structures based on the name of the respective block.